# Deploy a Language pack lp.cab for windows 7 ent with SCCM 2007 sp2

Tags: windows-7, sccm, language

Where and how am I able to add the lp.cab file within SCCM so that I can have the language pack install when Windows 7 and the apps are installed.
I want to add it to my task sequence but where is this option available.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is possible from within a SCCM 2007 Task Sequence, using the extra Task Sequence steps provided when you integrate MDT ([Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx)) into SCCM 2007 (this is a free download from Microsoft). Once you've integrated MDT you get a set of new MDT "Solution Accelerator" steps that you can add into your Task Sequence, as below.

[image: MDT Task Sequence - Install Language Packs]

While your machine is still in the PE phase of the build (ie *before* the "Setup Windows and ConfigMgr" step) you need to add a "Use Toolkit Package" and "Gather" step and then add a "Install Language Packs Offline" step

[image]

In the Install Language Pack Offline step, point the step to a Package that contains the 'lp.cab' file for your language inside a folder named with the [language's code](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd744369%28WS.10%29.aspx), and it will add the language into your OS before the OS first boots.

[image]

Lots more info here: [Customising Windows 7 deployments - part 4. Deploying Language Packs Offline](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/nbrady/archive/2011/02/15/customising-windows-7-deployments-part-4-deploying-language-packs-offline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this in SCCM by itself.  But there are other free tools out there that can help you out.  It will just require a little work on your part.

Use Windows System Image Manager in conjunction with Windows Automated Installation Kit OR the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (which integrates into SCCM) to create an answer file that customizes your Windows install.  With it, you can set the default language for for your install.  Here is the link to the TechNet reference for WAIK: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(WS.10).aspx.  The link to MDT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do it using System Center Configuration Manager you have to edit the Windows Image, the `.WIM` file, of that sequence task.

You can add the File using the command `DISM` avaibale in the free download [Microsoft AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5188).

The procedure to add the language pack with `DISM` is here, in this Microsoft Technet article: [Add and Remove Language Packs Offline](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799306%28WS.10%29.aspx)